For those who have experience with comparator circuits being used as detection devices, would you mind evaluating my thinking?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I am currently building a circuit to use with the "raindrop" sensors you can buy on Amazon for a  water detection project. They are continuity type sensors that are essentially PCBs that have little traces that run along side each other and when water drops bridge the gap between the traces, a connection is made. The sensors have little comparator circuits included with them that use 20mA of constant current because they include a bunch of LEDs and things I don't really need. Here is a picture of the schematic.

Figure 1: Raindrop sensor schematic from Amazon 1
I built another circuit because power consumption is very important to me: I built it using the built in circuit creator here. I went with these comparators because they are one of the more affordable comparators in the LTSpice default model package and I could not for the life of me get an LM308 model to work in LTSpice. I plan on connecting the outputs of these comparators to the Schmidt trigger input of an MSP430 microcontroller. What are your guy's thoughts on the design? Any pitfalls you see right off the bat? The simulation in LTSpice behaves the way I want, but I don't have a way off the top of my head to simulate the connection made to the microcontroller and test the output nodes other than testing them directly as is.
References:
1 "HiLetgo 3pcs LM393 Rain Drops Sensor Weather Moisture Monitor Sensor Humidity Sensitivity Module Nickeled Plate 3.3-5V for Arduino" [Online]. Available: "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01DK29K28/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1" [Accessed 19 October 2024]

The LT1017 doesn't need output pull-up resistors, because it has a pseudo push-pull output. Unfortunately, that output will draw over 200uA of current when low. If you're really concerned with power consumption, go with a proper push-pull device, requiring no pull-up resistor, and producing no associated quiescent current, such as the LTC6702.

It's not an efficient or accurate method and depends on  airborne contaminants to create the resistance.  It may work but fail (false +) in high humidity with dust accumulation.
It would be best to find one that compares capacitance and not resistance.  It is possible to do this with very low current (<mA) at low voltage using a clock to pass thru the sensor.  Water has a capacitance 80 times air for any gap and is fairly stable unlike contamination resistance with more uncertainty.
